# ARKit recognize more images

Tags: ios, arkit, image-recognition

I need to create `AR` app that can recognize a lot of images and display video over them. These images will be changing over time, and will be updated from the internet. `ARKit` has a limitation of `25` images to be recognized. Is there some way to achieve more `targets` possible? I can't use `location` to limit current context, because these are usually just covers of magazines, so they don't have location assigned. I can't also use `Vuforia`, because this application should be later prepared as separate apps for many customers, and I don't want to pay 500$ for each app license. I would love to make it work with `ARKit` somehow. Is there maybe some other way to recognize more images with `ARKit`?